# msDropDown working only on WP homepage?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html-select

I am using this javascript plugin for styling select/dropdown menu.
https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown

I am using it with wordpress, and it working well anywhere on homepage, but when i try to use it on other pages it simply wont work. 
There is no difference in homepage and other pages, they all call header & footer.
In header i jquery 1.7.2 and jquery.dd.min.js and then `$(".selectC").msDropDown();`

I am not getting any errors, nothing, it simply won't style select boxes on other pages.
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Any error in Developer Tool Console?

Comment: Nope, no errors. On HP it works wherever i put select and class "selectC" but it fails on other pages.